What unit of measurement does Apache Directory Server use for its cache size?
I have a very large ldap server, 20GB, in Apache Directory Server that I am trying to fine tune. I believe cache size is usually in Kilobytes, but I want to know for sure, because nowhere in apache directory studio does it say what the unit is.
I've built various smaller servers and guessed at optimal cache sizes settling for response times that are good enough. For this large server, I really need to find out what number I should use to cache 40% of the total server but I do not know the cache size unit of measurement.
